# Webpack Sass import URL resolving

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack

I'm building a web application using React and Webpack with this directory structure

```
/src
    /components
    /containers
        App.js
        App.scss
    /assets
        /fonts
            MarkOT/
                MarkOT.css
                MarkOT.eot
                ...
            ...
        /images
    /styles
        _vars.scss
```

I'm trying to import `_vars.scss` from `App.scss` like so:

```
@import '../../styles/vars';
```

and that works just fine. What doesn't work is if I have imports inside of `_vars.scss`

```
@import "../assets/fonts/MarkOT-ExtraLight/MarkOT-ExtraLight.css";
@import "../assets/fonts/MarkOT-Light/MarkOT-Light.css";
@import "../assets/fonts/MarkOT/MarkOT.css";
@import "../assets/fonts/MarkOT-Medium/MarkOT-Medium.css";
@import "../assets/fonts/MarkOT-Book/MarkOT-Book.css";
```

where those imports should resolve relative to the `styles` folder. Instead the imports are getting resolved relative to `containers/App/App.scss`. I read on `sass-loader`s website that one should use the `resolve-url-loader` to solve this issue but I can't get it to work.

An import to like `@import "~../assets/fonts/MarkOT-ExtraLight/MarkOT-ExtraLight.css";` just contains a `@font-face` declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MarkOT';
  src: url('MarkOT.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  url('MarkOT.otf')  format('opentype'),
     url('MarkOT.woff') format('woff'), url('MarkOT.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('MarkOT.svg#MarkOT') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
      app: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/client/index.js'),
      vendors: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    pathInfo: true,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    css: 'main.css'
  },
  module: {
     preLoaders: [
        {
         test: /\.js?$/,
         loader: "eslint-loader",
         exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ],
     loaders: [
      {
        test: /src\/.+.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.scss?$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', '!css?sourceMap!resolve-url!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-bourbon').includePaths) +
    '&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-neat').includePaths[1])) }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ]
   },
   plugins: [
     new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
     new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
  ]
 };
```

This line in particular is for handling my styles:

```
{ test: /\.scss?$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', '!css?sourceMap!resolve-url!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-bourbon').includePaths) +
    '&includePaths[]=' + encodeURIComponent(require('node-neat').includePaths[1])) }
```

As it said on the `resolve-url-loader` website, I included source maps in both the `sass` and `css` loaders (as well as included paths to the bourbon and neat libraries, all of which loads fine).

Is there something blatantly obvious I'm missing that I can't see?

EDIT:

I was able to workaround the issue by creating a `_font.scss` file in the same directory as `_var.scss`, moving all the `@font-face` declarations into `_font.scss` and then replacing all the instances of `url` with `require` inside the font declarations.

I don't love that I wasn't able to figure out why the other one was working but it works so that's good. What I found interesting is that `url` didn't work, I was under the impression that `css-loader` took care of that.

Comment: Would also love to hear a proper solution to this problem without having to hack the source files. In my case I'm trying to load in `.scss` files for Foundation 6. The `foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss` file loads fine, but the @import statements do not get included.

Comment: The `@import` statements are handled, at least in my case, by three things: 1) Resolved aliases in the webpack config object itself so instead of doing `@import '../../styles/vars'` I can do `@import 'styles/vars'`.  2) including the .scss for foundation as an entry point in the config (similar to how font-awesome recommends you do it). And 3) in the css-loader, using the `importLoaders` param. What that does is basically say hey for X (where x is the value of the param), apply x amount of loaders that follow the css loader to my `@import` statements.

Comment: @jpunk11 I can post a full solution if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me try your suggestions first tomorrow and if I am still stuck it would be great to see your full solution.

Comment: After playing with all your suggestions I realized that the `@imports` were in fact working, but the imported sass code wasn't being outputted as css as I would expect from code like this:

// my-main.scss
`
@import "~foundation-sites/scss/foundation";
`

What I found was that the variables set in the foundation files were available in my code after the import.

To get the code to output I found Foundation's mixin namely `foundation-everything` and added it in my code.

// my-main.scss
`
@import "~foundation-sites/scss/foundation";

@include foundation-everything(true);
`

Comment: You need to make sure webpack is configured to handle all the file types that  you require. It looks like your webpack config, specifically the regex `/\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$/`, does not handle `eot` required by `url('MarkOT.eot?#iefix')`, `otf`, and others.

Answer (score 7):

in your webpack.config

```
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [ 'src', 'node_modules' ],
    alias: {
      styles: /*put the base folder of your styles here*/
    }
  }
```

and then in your stylesheet import using a @styles then the relative path

```
@import '~styles/yourStyle.scss';
```